# Make ListView Item transparent and in press light white

Tags: android, android-listview, transparent

How can I make the listView like in the following ScreenShot

[image]

It is transparent and when press item it becomes light white.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a drawable file to put as the background for the listview item.

drawable/custom_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

In your styles.xml file,

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...
    <!-- Colors -->
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

</resources>
```

In list view adapter,

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ...
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_background);
}
```

Just tried it. It works.

Comment: It tells me that the Color not allowed for drawable with value #FFFFFFFF & #00000000

Comment: @Eman87 try #0000 for transparent and #8FFF for light white. Change the 8 value, in a range of 0 - 9 and A - F to make it more or less transparent

Comment: @Aswin `view.setBackground(R.drawable.custom_background);` it must be `setBackgroundResource`, isn't it??

Comment: @Aswin .. You answer works with me, but I noticed two things: first, is that when press it becomes white, I want it light white or transparent white like in screenshot not exactly white. the second thing is that when I scroll, the background becomes black some while then back as it.

Comment: You can change the colors to anything you want. Light white will #80ffffff. The first two letters control the alpha so adjust to what you want.

Comment: But Why the background becomes black when scrolling ??

Comment: ok, I found solution for the black when scrolling by adding `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` Thank you for your help.